# Trying to get a count in 3 tables on MySql

Tags: mysql

So I have 3 tables in a database
One is hotel which has hotel_id and status
one is partner which has partner_id and partner_name
and one is partner_hotel which has hotel_id and partner_id

What I am trying to get is the count for each partner that has a hotel with the status = 1

The closest I have gotten is

```
select p.partner_name,count(hotel_id)
from partner_hotel ph
join partner p on p.partner_id = ph.partner_id
group by ph.partner_id;
```

The problem is that does not limit to ones with a status of 1 and nothing I seem to be doing seems to work.

Comment: `wHERE ph.status = 1`?

Comment: I have tried that nearly everywhere I could think, where would you suggest entering that?

Comment: Please read this.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should join hotel  too  if th hotel contain status and group by  p.partner_id

```
    select p.partner_name,count(*)
    from partner_hotel ph
    inner join partner p on p.partner_id = ph.partner_id
    inner join hotel h on ph.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
    where h.status = 1
    group by p.partner_id;
```

or ig hotel use id

```
    select p.partner_name,count(*)
    from partner_hotel ph
    inner join partner p on p.partner_id = ph.partner_id
    inner join hotel h on ph.hotel_id = h.id
    where h.status = 1
    group by p.partner_id;
```

Comment: I had tried something similar before but get error 1054 unknown column h.hotel_id in on clause

Comment: answer  updated  .. wrong column name .. are you sure that hotel table contain  hotel_id and not simply id ?????

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to find the number of partners with one or more hotels having a status = 1. If my guess is correct, this gets you the one number.

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.partner_id) partner_count
   FROM partner p
   JOIN partner_hotel ph ON p.partner_id = ph.partner_id
   JOIN hotel h ON ph.hotel_id = h.hotel_id AND h.status = 1
```

If your requirement is to show one result row for each partner showing the number of hotels with status = 1, that will go like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) hotel_count,
       p.partner_id
   FROM partner p
   JOIN partner_hotel ph ON p.partner_id = ph.partner_id
   JOIN hotel h ON ph.hotel_id = h.hotel_id AND h.status = 1
  GROUP BY p.partner_id
```

**Pro tip:** When preparing to write a query, it's helpful to imagine the result set you want. Ask yourself these questions:

1. How many rows must the result set have?
2. It should have one row per ____  (row per what? Hotel, Partner, Guest, Hotel with status = 1?).
3. Each row should show ____  values?

If you do this work of imagination, writing the query will be much easier.

Comment: What I am trying to find is how many hotels with a status = 1 each partner has.

Comment: got it working with
SELECT COUNT(*) hotel_count,
       p.partner_id
   FROM partner p
   JOIN partner_hotel ph ON p.partner_id = ph.partner_id
   JOIN hotel ON ph.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id AND hotel.status = 1
  GROUP BY p.partner_name;

But not sure how to show results by name rather than id